# Can't start MySQL server on OSX

Tags: macos, mysql

I just installed MySQL Server and Startup tools from the DMG at the  MySQL site on an OSX 10.6.6. I restarted the computer, but it seems it can't connect to its socket.

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I try starting the server

```
$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe &
[2] 917
```

But I still get

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I can't seem to find the socket file

```
$ ls /tmp/mysql*
ls: /tmp/mysql*: No such file or directory
$ ls /var/lib/mysql*
ls: /var/lib/mysql*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start server and add the root user.

#### Starting the server:

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` , **or**

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &` , **or**

`sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start`

#### Add root user:

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password your_password`

Comment: `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` is what works for me

Comment: ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file .... ?

Answer (score 1):

Just start your Mysql-Server like this:

service mysql start

Comment: i know 'service' command works in ubuntu, but macOS? don't think so